# Media Breakpoints work as it should locally and live (using inspect tool for all media breakpoints) but not on mobile device

Tags: html, css, media-queries

So everything works as it should locally and even live (but only on my computer) but when i visit the site on my phone it seems to ignore my media.css

I thought it was a breakpoint issue. So i logged onto the site from my computer and inspected the page and set it to the same resolution as my cellphone landscape mode (823x412) and everything works as it should.

but when i log onto the same site on my phone it just doesn't work. I have no idea what's causing this.

[this is the site](https://moenegm.ga)

```css
/*from main .css */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*---------BODY & BACKGROUND-----------*/
body {
  background-image: url("/Images/Iphonexbackground.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: "Merienda";
  color: rgb(200, 150, 15);
  font-size: 0.8em;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
footer {
  height: 5vh;
  background-color: rgb(33, 33, 33);
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}
/*---------HEADING & MAIN SCREEN STUFF-----------*/
#home {
  background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.9);
  max-width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 20vh);
  padding-top: 15vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  text-align: center;
}
.largeHeading {
  padding-bottom: 2vh;
}
.smallHeading {
  padding-bottom: 50vh;
}
.moe {
  color: white;
}
.social a {
  color: rgb(200, 150, 15);
}
.social a:hover {
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
/*------------------ROTATING MENU BUTTON----------------------*/
.menuButton {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  right: 35px;
  top: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.buttonLine {
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.close > .buttonLine:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(405deg) translate(5px, 5px);
}
.close > .buttonLine:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.close > .buttonLine:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-405deg) translate(5px, -5px);
}
/*------------------------------FULL MENU----------------------------*/
.menu {
  max-width: 100vh;
}
/*Menu is closed by default*/
.menuWrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.show > .menuWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*----------------------PORTRAIT MENU-----------------------*/
/*handles image*/
.myPortrait {
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}
.show > .portrait {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url("/Images/Portrait.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  border: 3px solid rgb(200, 150, 15);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.show > .myPortrait {
  visibility: visible;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(33, 33, 33);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
/*----------------------LINK MENU-----------------------*/
.navLink {
  color: rgb(200, 150, 15);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.current > a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.navItem a:hover {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.menuItems {
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
}
.navItem {
  transform: translate3d(600px, 0, 0);
}
/*handles menue items*/
.show > .menuItems {
  visibility: visible;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(33, 33, 33);
  list-style: none;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
/*Delays each individual link movments
coming from the right side*/
.show > .navItem:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  color: brown;
}
.show > .navItem:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  color: brown;
}
.show > .navItem:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  color: brown;
}
.show > .navItem:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
  color: brown;
}
.show > .navItem:nth-child(5) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
  color: brown;
}
.show > .navItem:nth-child(6) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
  color: brown;
}
.show > .navItem:nth-child(7) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.7s;
  color: brown;
}
.show > .navItem:nth-child(8) {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 0.8s;
  color: brown;
}
/*from contact.css*/
.contactContainer {
  background: rgb(66, 66, 66);
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 85vh;
  min-height: 475px;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  padding-top: 10vh;
  color: black;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.company-info {
  background: rgb(200, 150, 15);
  border: 1px solid rgb(200, 150, 15);
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.company-info > h3,
.company-info > ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.contactForm {
  background: rgb(243, 227, 183);
  border: 1px solid rgb(200, 150, 15);
  width: 96%;
  height: 75%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
.letsChat {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: rgb(200, 150, 15);
  text-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}
.contactForm input {
  border: 1px solid rgb(200, 150, 15);
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
.contactForm textarea {
  border: 1px solid rgb(200, 150, 15);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.contactForm button {
  background-color: rgb(200, 150, 15);
  border: 1px solid rgb(200, 150, 15);
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.contactForm button:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.full {
  grid-column: 1/3;
}
.req {
  color: red;
}

/*from media.css*/
@media only screen and (min-height: 350px) and (max-height: 500px) and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 825px) {
  body {
    background-image: url("/Images/Background.jpg");
  }
  .smallHeading {
    padding-bottom: 45vh;
  }
  #about {
    grid-gap: 0vh;
  }
  .aboutWrapper {
    height: 45vh;
  }
  .social {
    height: 6vh;
  }
  .contactContainer {
    height: 75vh;
    min-height: 75vh;
    padding-top: 20vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 3fr;
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  .company-info {
    height: 90%;
  }
  .contactForm {
    height: 90%;
  }
  .contactForm input {
    height: 25px;
  }
  .contactForm textarea {
    height: 65px;
  }
  .contactForm button {
    height: 1.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/main.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/contact.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/media.css" />
  <title>Contact-Mohamed Negm</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="menuButton">
      <div class="buttonLine"></div>
      <div class="buttonLine"></div>
      <div class="buttonLine"></div>
    </div>
    <nav class="menu">
      <div class="menuWrapper">
        <div class="myPortrait">
          <div class="portrait"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="menuItems">
          <li class="navItem"><a href="/" class="navLink">HOME </a></li>
          <li class="navItem">
            <a href="about.html" class="navLink">ABOUT ME </a>
          </li>
          <li class="navItem current">
            <a href="contact.html" class="navLink">CONTACT </a>
          </li>
          <li class="navItem">
            <a href="animationPortfolio.html" class="navLink">ANIMATION PORTFOLIO
              </a>
          </li>
          <li class="navItem">
            <a href="developerPortfolio.html" class="navLink">DEVELOPER PORTFOLIO
              </a>
          </li>
          <li class="navItem">
            <a href="educatorPortfolio.html" class="navLink">EDUCATOR PORTFOLIO
              </a>
          </li>
          <li class="navItem">
            <a href="photographyPortfolio.html" class="navLink">PHOTOGRAPHY PORTFOLIO
              </a>
          </li>
          <li class="navItem">
            <a href="videographyPortfolio.html" class="navLink">VIDEOGRAPHY PORTFOLIO
              </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main class="contactContainer">
    <div class="company-info">
      <h3>Mohamed A. Negm</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><i class="fa fa-road"></i> Brooklyn NY</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> (917) 930-0000</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> mr.negm90@gmail.com</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <form class="contactForm" action="https://formspree.io/mr.negm90@gmail.com" method="POST">
      <h3 class="letsChat">Let's Chat</h3>
      <p>
        <label>Name<span class="req">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" required />
      </p>
      <p><label>Company</label> <input type="text" name="company" /></p>
      <p>
        <label>Email Address<span class="req">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" name="_replyto" required />
      </p>
      <p><label>Phone Number</label> <input type="text" name="phone" /></p>
      <p class="full">
        <label>Message<span class="req">*</span></label>
        <textarea name="message" rows="5" required></textarea>
      </p>
      <p class="full"><button>Submit</button></p>
    </form>
  </main>
  <footer>Copyright &copy; 2019</footer>
  <script src="/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try getting rid of the min-height and max-height part in you media queries to see if the issue persist.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I figured out the problem and posted the answer below. Thanks again for at least trying to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the problem.

before hand I was doing this:

```
@media only screen and (min-height: 350px) and (max-height: 500px) and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 825px) {..}
```

This was confusing the browser because it had four parameters or exceptions min-width AND max-width AND min-height AND max-height

what worked for me was when I changed it from four to three so like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 825px) and (max-height: 500px) {...}
```

this is less calculations on the browser and less exceptions to handle.

I'm happy to say the problem is solved and the case is closed. Even though someone voted down this question I hope this answer helps someone one day as I was truly struggling with this for a while.